# Setup catch-all email without G-Suite?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-cloud-platform, gmail-imap

I'd like to setup a catch-all email for my domain-name. From what I understand I can do this in Gmail if I have G-Suite. But I don't need G-Suite, literally the only thing I need is a catch-all email address and that's it. No Google Drive, no Adwords, no office stuff that comes with G-Suite. Literally the one and only thing I need or want is a catch-all email address with my domain. Is there any way to do this without having G-Suite? If so, how?

Comment: Which ISP services your domain and your email server and with what kind of account? What email software do you use?

Comment: I'm using Namecheap shared hosting. At the moment I'm using IMAP via the built-in Windows 10 mail client. But I'd like to get a better webmail client (hence Gmail) because Roundcube and Horde suck.

https://www.namecheap.com/hosting/shared/

Comment: I think that for Gmail catch-all you need G-Suite.